# How can we convert Notebooks under Azure Machine Learning into Azure Web Service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service

I have written a Jupyter notebook in Azure Machine Learning which executes without issue. Now, I have to publish the code as a web service. "[From Jupyter Notebook to Azure Web App in 5 Easy Steps](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/from-jupyter-notebook-to-azure-web-app-in-5-easy-steps-2783f8fd847d)" describes converting a notebook into webservice using Docker and Azure Container Registry

Is there any alternative simple method within azure machine learning to convert the notebook into a web service? This can be done in the designer section:

[image: see screenshot].

Comment: what does the notebook do? make a model? score new data against a model? please include more information.

Answer (score 2):

The "Designer" section of Azure ML is just a UI for creating Azure Machine Learning Pipelines. You can publish Pipelines as a "web service". Note that this is different than deploying a model as a webservice. Unfortunately, the Designer UI does not currently support [`NotebookRunnerStep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-contrib-notebook/azureml.contrib.notebook.notebookrunnerstep?view=azure-ml-py), but the SDK does. So your options are:

- Use the SDK to define an Azure ML Pipeline with a `NotebookRunnerStep`, or
- turn your notebook into a Python script and use the Designer to create a Pipeline with a `PythonScriptStep` step

Comment: @RKK if this answers your question, please click the green check mark to accept it! If not, please follow up!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have already tried the python script option. It requires an external module to import which was throwing an error. I shall try the first option (using SDK). Thanks once again.

Comment: @RKK the SDK has a relatively steep learning curve, but the payoff is great!

Comment: hmm.. Let me try SDK option. Thanks once again.